# Extending the Law of Cosines formula to quadrilaterals (and even polygon?)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, polygons, quadrilateral

Let's take a look back at this familiar "Law of cosines":

> ‎Consider‎ the ‎triangle ‎$\triangle‎‎ ABC$. Let $a = BC, b = AC, c = AB$; $\angle A, \angle B, \angle C$ are the angles of the triangle opposite to side $a, b, c,$ respectively. By the Law of Cosines:
>   $$a^{2‎} = b^{2‎} + c^{2‎} - 2bc \cdot \cos \angle A$$

This formula can apply for any triangle.

But what about quadrilaterals? Is there a formula, which shows the relationship between sides and angles, similar to the Law of Cosines? Can we extend the Law of Cosines???

This is the way to approach the formula for quadrilaterals (*It's not (really) a proof*):

> Given the quadrilateral ABCD. Let $a = BC, b = CD, c = AB, d = AD$. Let $E = AB \cap CD$ and $G = AC \cap BD$

Let consider $\triangle ABC$ as a "special quadrilateral" (where $d=0$). Then by the Law of Cosines:

$$a^{2‎} = b^{2‎} + c^{2‎} - 2bc \cdot \cos \angle BEC = b^{2‎} + c^{2‎} - 2bc \cdot \cos \angle BGC$$

(because when $d=0$, $E \equiv G \equiv A \Rightarrow \angle BEC = \angle BGC$)

Notice that when $d=0$ then $CA = CD = CE = b$; $BD = BE = BA = c$. So we can guess the general formula for a quadrilateral will be one of these two formulas:

> $$ a^{2‎} + Kd^{2‎} = b^{2‎} + c^{2‎} - 2 \cdot BE \cdot CE \cdot \cos \angle BEC \text{ (1)}$$
>   $$ a^{2‎} + Kd^{2‎} = b^{2‎} + c^{2‎} - 2 \cdot BD \cdot CA \cdot \cos \angle BGC \text{ (2)}$$

(where $K$ is a constant)

The reason we add $Kd^{2‎}$ is to make the formula homogeneous (since the Law of Cosines is also homogeneous), and when $d=0$, the $Kd^{2‎}$ term is gone. Moreover, from our intuition, if the formula contains $\angle BEC$, then two sides, which multiply to its cosines, have to be $BE$ and $CE$. Otherwise, those two sides will be $BD$ and $CA$ multiplied by $\cos \angle BGC$

To see which one is possibly correct, we can try to apply the formula to a special quadrilateral: square. In a square, $a=b=c=d$, "$BE = CE = \infty$", "$\angle BEC = \infty$", $\angle BGC = 90^{\circ}$. Apply $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$(1): a^{2‎} + Ka^{2‎} = a^{2‎} + a^{2‎} - \infty$$
$$(2): a^{2‎} + Ka^{2‎} = a^{2‎} + a^{2‎}$$

$(1)$ is definitely wrong. The formula $(2)$ can be true if $K=1$, so let re-written it:

$$a^{2‎} + d^{2‎} = b^{2‎} + c^{2‎} - 2 \cdot BD \cdot CA \cdot \cos \angle BGC$$

To be sure that this formula is correct, let's apply this in another quadrilateral. This time is a rectangle, where $\angle BGC = 60^{\circ}$. We have $a=d, b=c=a\sqrt{3}$, $BD = AC = 2a$. Apply the formula that we've just found, we get:

$$a^{2‎} + a^{2‎} = 3a^{2‎} + 3a^{2‎} - 2 \cdot 4a^{2‎} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

And this is true. You can verify it with some other quadrilaterals, and it'll also true. So, our new extended "Law of Cosines" is:

> $$a^{2‎} + d^{2‎} = b^{2‎} + c^{2‎} - 2 \cdot BD \cdot CA \cdot \cos \angle BGC$$

So that seems fine. But

> *Is there a proof of the formula above*?

Now, my main question (and my main focus) is:

> ***Can we extend the formula (find a general formula) for polygons with n sides***?

This question is what I'm looking for (*This isn't a homework question*). I'm really curious about this. If you have an answer (or just an idea) to approach, please provide it.

Thank you a lot and have a nice day :D

Comment: A quadrilateral with four known side lengths is a mechanism, so the angles cannot be determined. It you know an angle, you solve by triangulating the quadrilateral. In many (all?) cases, you solve the polygons by preliminary triangulation.

Comment: I can agree with you. I think the formula may be at least useful somehow. My main focus is to extend the formula (if possible), even if it's useful or not

Comment: @Allawonder I'll point that. Thanks. But do you think is there a possible general formula (similar to Law of Cosines) for a polygon with n sides? I'm just curious. I think that extends the formula is a good way to learn and understand math better.

Comment: There is a version for polygons inscribed in a circle.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @KiênP.S. : It's my own. Remind me of it about eight hours from now and I'll say somewhat more about it.

Comment: Well it's 12 hours now:)

Comment: @KiênP.S. : Look at the following answer for the case of an octagon inscribed in a circle: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564255/find-circumradius-of-an-octagon/3564353#3564353

Comment: @KiênP.S. $\ldots\,$and in reading that answer, you may way to start with the part about the sum of squares of the lengths of the eight sides.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider convex $n$-gon $A_1A_2\cdots A_n$ where $\overline{A_jA_{j+1}}=a_j$ with $\angle{A_jA_{j+1}A_{j+2}}=\theta_j$.

Now, let us put our $n$-gon on the $xy$ plane in the following way :

- $A_1$ is at the origin
- The side $A_1A_2$ is on the $x$-axis
- The $x$-coordinate of $A_2$ is positive
- The $y$-coordinate of $A_3$ is positive.

Here, if we consider the projection of each side on the $x$-axis, then we get
$$a_1+a_2\cos(\pi-\theta_1)+a_3\cos(2\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2))+\cdots +a_n\cos((n-1)\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2+\cdots +\theta_{n-1}))=0$$
which can be written as
$$a_1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}a_{k+1}\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k}\theta_j\bigg)\tag1$$

Similarly, if we consider the projection of each side on the $y$-axis, then we get
$$a_2\sin(\pi-\theta_1)+a_3\sin(2\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2))+\cdots +a_n\sin((n-1)\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2+\cdots +\theta_{n-1}))=0$$
which can be written as
$$0=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}a_{k+1}\sin\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k}\theta_j\bigg)\tag2$$

From $(1)(2)$, we obtain 
$$a_1^2+0^2=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}a_{k+1}\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k}\theta_j\bigg)\bigg)^2+\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}a_{k+1}\sin\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k}\theta_j\bigg)\bigg)^2$$
which can be written as
$$a_1^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k+1}^2+\sum_{1\le p\lt q\le n-1}\bigg(2(-1)^{p+1}a_{p+1}\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\theta_j\bigg)\times (-1)^{q+1}a_{q+1}\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{q}\theta_j\bigg)+2(-1)^{p+1}a_{p+1}\sin\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\theta_j\bigg)\times (-1)^{q+1}a_{q+1}\sin\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{q}\theta_j\bigg)\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$a_1^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k+1}^2+\sum_{1\le p\lt q\le n-1}2(-1)^{p+q}a_{p+1}a_{q+1}\bigg(\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\theta_j\bigg)\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{q}\theta_j\bigg)+\sin\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\theta_j\bigg)\sin\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{q}\theta_j\bigg)\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$a_1^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k+1}^2+\sum_{1\le p\lt q\le n-1}2(-1)^{p+q}a_{p+1}a_{q+1}\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{q}\theta_j-\sum_{j=1}^{p}\theta_j\bigg)$$
Therefore, we get
$$\color{red}{a_1^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k+1}^2+\sum_{1\le p\lt q\le n-1}2(-1)^{p+q}a_{p+1}a_{q+1}\cos\bigg(\sum_{j=p+1}^{q}\theta_j\bigg)}$$

---

For example, for pentagon $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5\ (n=5)$, we get

$$\color{red}{a_1^2=a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2+a_5^2-2a_{2}a_{3}\cos(\theta_2)+2a_{2}a_{4}\cos(\theta_2+\theta_3)-2a_{2}a_{5}\cos(\theta_2+\theta_3+\theta_4)-2a_{3}a_{4}\cos(\theta_3)+2a_{3}a_{5}\cos(\theta_3+\theta_4)-2a_{4}a_{5}\cos(\theta_4)}$$

---

**Added** : One can get several formulas.

**For quadrilateral $A_1A_2A_3A_4\ (n=4)$ :**

- If we change $(1)(2)$ to $$(1)\implies a_4\cos(\theta_4)=a_1-a_2\cos(\theta_1)+a_3\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)$$$$(2)\implies a_4\sin(\theta_4)=a_2\sin(\theta_1)-a_3\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)$$squaring and adding give
  $$a_4^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2-2a_1a_2\cos(\theta_1)-2a_2a_3\cos(\theta_2)+2a_1a_3\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)$$
- If we change $(1)(2)$ to $$(1)\implies a_1+a_3\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=a_2\cos(\theta_1)+a_4\cos(\theta_4)$$$$(2)\implies a_3\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)=a_2\sin(\theta_1)-a_4\sin(\theta_4)$$squaring and adding give
  $$a_1^2+a_3^2+2a_1a_3\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=a_2^2+a_4^2+2a_2a_4\cos(\theta_1+\theta_4)$$
- If we change $(1)(2)$ to $$(1)\implies a_3\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)-a_2\cos(\theta_1)=a_4\cos(\theta_4)-a_1$$$$(2)\implies a_3\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)-a_2\sin(\theta_1)=-a_4\sin(\theta_4)$$squaring and adding give
  $$a_2^2+a_3^2-2a_2a_3\cos(\theta_2)=a_1^2+a_4^2-2a_1a_4\cos(\theta_4)$$

**For pentagon $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5\ (n=5)$ :**

- If we change $(1)(2)$ to $$(1)\implies a_1-a_2\cos(\theta_1)+a_3\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=a_5\cos(\theta_5)-a_4\cos(\theta_4+\theta_5)$$$$(2)\implies a_2\sin(\theta_1)-a_3\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)=a_5\sin(\theta_5)-a_4\sin(\theta_4+\theta_5)$$squaring and adding give
  $$a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2-2a_1a_2\cos(\theta_1)-2a_2a_3\cos(\theta_2)+2a_1a_3\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=a_4^2+a_5^2-2a_4a_5\cos(\theta_4)$$

Comment: PERFECT! Verified this formula for some polygons and it's true for all. Thank you so much:D!

Comment: @KiênP.S.: You are welcome. I've just added some explanations about the fact that there are several formulas.

Comment: Thanks. I'll point this fact.

Comment: @mathlove How did you get $a_1+a_2\cos(\pi-\theta_1)+a_3\cos(2\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2))+\cdots +a_n\cos((n-1)\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2+\cdots +\theta_{n-1}))=0$ from considering the projection of each side on the x-axis?

Comment: @windows prime : Well, if you draw an $n$-gon in the way written in the answer, and find the angles inside or outside the $n$-gon, you should be able to see how I got the equation.

Comment: OK Now I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In quadrilateral $ABCD$, in addition to $a = BC$, $b = CD$, $c = AB$, $d = AD$,
also set:
$$
AG=e,\quad CG=f,\quad BG=g,\quad DG=h,\quad \angle BGC=\alpha,
$$
where $G$ is the intersection point of diagonals $AC$ and $BD$.
By the cosine law we get then:
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &=f^2+g^2-2fg\cos\alpha \\
d^2 &=e^2+h^2-2eh\cos\alpha \\
b^2 &=f^2+h^2+2fh\cos\alpha \\
c^2 &=e^2+g^2+2eg\cos\alpha \\
\end{align}
$$
and from that we obtain:
$$
b^2+c^2-a^2-d^2 = 2(fh+eg+fg+eh)\cos\alpha=2(e+f)(g+h)\cos\alpha,
$$
which is precisely your formula.

Comment: Thanks for the proof:D

Answer (score 2):

Let $\vec{BC}=\vec{a},$ $\vec{CD}=\vec{b},$ $\vec{DA}=\vec{d}$ and $\vec{AB}=\vec{c}.$

Thus, since $$\vec{a}+\vec{c}=-\vec{b}-\vec{d},$$ we obtain: $$(\vec{a}+\vec{c})^2=(\vec{b}+\vec{d})^2,$$ which gives
$$\vec{a}\vec{c}-\vec{b}\vec{d}=\frac{1}{2}(b^2+d^2-a^2-c^2).$$
In another hand, $$BD\cdot AC\cos\measuredangle BGC=\vec{DB}\cdot\vec{AC}=(\vec{c}+\vec{d})(\vec{c}+\vec{a})=$$
$$=c^2+\vec{a}\vec{c}+\vec{d}(\vec{a}+\vec{c})=c^2+\vec{a}\vec{c}-\vec{d}(\vec{b}+\vec{d})=c^2-d^2+\vec{a}\vec{c}-\vec{b}\vec{d}=$$
$$=c^2-d^2+\frac{1}{2}(b^2+d^2-a^2-c^2)=\frac{1}{2}(b^2-d^2+c^2-a^2)$$ and we are done!

Comment: Very nice proof:)!
What about the 2nd question? Do you have an idea of how to approach it?