# Re-ordering the sides of a cyclic polygon doesn't change the circumradius

Tags: geometry

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564255/409), I got an answer regarding the circumradius for a cyclic octagon remaining constant even if I change the order of sides.

Why does this happen? Is there any formal proof of it other than the symmetry associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine cutting the octagon up into $8$ triangles, each bounded by two radii and a side.  Clearly, you can shuffle the into any order and put them back together into a different cyclic octagon by matching up the radii.